# ServiceStack on Heroku with PostgreSQL dabase json return format error

Tags: heroku, servicestack

I was setup ServiceStack on Heroku with PostgreSQL (follow http://friism.com/running-net-on-heroku). But json return format error, here is json

```
344
[{"Id":3,"Code":"EUR","Name":"Đồng EUR","RecVersion":3,"RecId":3,"RecCreated":"2013-09-13T07:29:30.7228990","RecCreatedBy":1,"Status":"1","RecModified":"2013-09-13T07:29:30.7228990","RecModifiedBy":1},{"Id":4,"Code":"JPY","Name":"Đồng Yên Nhật","RecVersion":4,"RecId":4,"RecCreated":"2013-09-13T07:29:30.7275190","RecCreatedBy":1,"Status":"1","RecModified":"2013-09-13T07:29:30.7275190","RecModifiedBy":1},{"Id":2,"Code":"USD","Name":"Đồng Đôla Mỹ","RecVersion":2,"RecId":2,"RecCreated":"2013-09-13T07:29:30.7183870","RecCreatedBy":1,"Status":"1","RecModified":"2013-09-13T07:29:30.7183870","RecModifiedBy":1},{"Id":1,"Code":"VND","Name":"Đồng Việt Nam","RecVersion":1,"RecId":1,"RecCreated":"2013-09-13T07:29:30.7121270","RecCreatedBy":1,"Status":"1","RecModified":"2013-09-13T07:29:30.7121270","RecModifiedBy":1}]

0
```

It include 344 and 0.

But if i follow

```
https://github.com/kunjee17/ServiceStackHeroku
```

json return is OK (http://thawing-shelf-3867.herokuapp.com/Rockstars?format=json)

How to fix it.
Thanks you very much

Comment: There's not enough information here to begin to help you.  The example you link to proves it's possible to host ServiceStack on heroku. That doesn't really help debug your code.  Can you confirm that your code, run locally on your PC, doesn't have the same problem?

Comment: On localhost it run well.  Here is my servicestack on [Heroku](http://blooming-inlet-4753.herokuapp.com/lookup/currency).  Here is on [AppHarbor](http://cerp.apphb.com/lookup/currency)

Answer (score 1):

The json doesn't include the extra numbers - if you click on the 'view json datasource' you'll see your expected json.  So, it's not the json format that's wrong.

If you look at the response (using Chrome Dev Tools Network Response tab, for example), you will see that the extra numbers are outside the html tags.
Something is adding extra characters to the ServiceStack response before it's delivered to the client.  I'd focus on your config settings. Perhaps it's related to a character encoding not being set correctly in nginx on Heroku?

[image]

Comment: I use REST Console JSON return is error (include extra numbers).  Dart HttpClient() function is too.

Comment: But when you run it locally you don't have the same problem.  So the difference is the hosting. On heroku your application is being proxied through an nginx server.  Any request you make to heroku (dart http client, rest console, etc. ) is being passed through the nginx server. I suspect that it's adding the extra characters to the servicestack request because of a configuration issue in the nginx setup on heroku.